# C# Async/Await: Leave AsyncLocal<T> context upon task creation

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

AsyncLocal allows us to keep context data on a async control flow. This is pretty neat since all following resumes (even on another thread) can retrieve and modify the ambient data ([AsyncLocal on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906268(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Is there any way to 'leave' the current async local context for a sub-task and thus create a new one?

```
AsyncLocal<string> Data = new AsyncLocal<string>();
Data.Value = "One";

Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
{
    string InnerValue = Data.Value;
    //InnerValue equals to "One", I need it to be null.
} );
```

In the example above, the inner task shares the AsyncLocal context with the outer control flow. Is there any way to enforce a new context?

Update: in order to solve my issue here, the following worked like a charm (despite the fact that it didn't entirely reset the context):

```
AsyncLocal<string> Data = new AsyncLocal<string>();
Data.Value = "One";

Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
{
    Data.Value = null;
    string InnerValue = Data.Value;
    //InnerValue equals to null now.
} );

string OuterValue = Data.Value; //Stays "one" even after the inner change.
```

Comment: I'm not understanding your question. The whole purpose of `AsyncLocal` is to flow the value between async calls, and you want the data not to flow? Then why are you using it in the first place?

Comment: Maybe just old plain scope: `{ string inner = ... } // inner not defined here`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.executioncontext.suppressflow?view=netcore-2.1#System_Threading_ExecutionContext_SuppressFlow):

```
AsyncLocal<string> Data = new AsyncLocal<string>();
Data.Value = "One";

using (ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow())
{    
    Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
    {
        string InnerValue = Data.Value;
        //InnerValue is null.
    } );
}
```

Note that this may have side-effects, such as no longer producing proper stack traces. However, since you ignore the result of `StartNew`, i.e. you seem to not be interested in actually *having* a flow, this would be the correct thing to do.

Alternatively, and more in line with the solution in your own update, remember that `AsyncLocal` is scoped, i.e. if you set the value in a nested async operation, it does not affect the value in your outer function. This means that you can reset `AsyncLocal`s first thing in the nested operation without destroying the values for the outer operation.

Answer (score -6):

You must use instead ThreadLocal

```
AsyncLocal<string> Data = new AsyncLocal<string>();
ThreadLocal<string> Data1 = new ThreadLocal<string>();
Data.Value = "One";
Data1.Value = "Two";

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
  string InnerValue = Data.Value; //InnerValue equals to "One", 
  string InnerValue1 = Data1.Value; //InnerValue1 equals to null, 
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your input. The problem however is that I have to work with AsyncLocal in order to retain context for a logging framework. So I somehow need to "reset" the async context, since I need to work with one outside and one inside.

Comment: This is nonsense. `ThreadLocal` might happen to be null because the task might happen to be on a different thread, but that's in no way guaranteed. `ThreadLocal` and async/await do not, in general, mix well; there are only some very specific uses for it.